# Converting my wordpress theme into a bootstrap responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to convert my wordpress theme into a bootstrap responsive... i search all the ways in internet but didnt found any good stuff to solve my issue.. A bunch of thanks in advance for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bootstrap Starter Theme for wordpress](http://www.rootstheme.com/)

Here another starter theme [Bootstrap Wordpress starter theme](http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/)

Comment: I provided him the place where he can start. If it wouldnt have helped , he could have not selected the answer. Also his question was broad enough and cant be answered just theoretically.